# PHP $_SESSION not shared between requests

Tags: php, loops, session

I am playing with long polling and trying to stop the script started by an AJAX call if a new request happens.
This is the PHP code that is started by an AJAX request:

```
$checker = $_SESSION['checker'] = time();

while (true) {
    if ($checker != $_SESSION['checker']) {
          $out = 'new one started';
          break;
     }

    if (some other condition) {
           $out = 'smth done or happend';
           break;
    }

    sleep(3); 
}

echo $out;
```

I have been doing some logging and it looks like `$_SESSION['checker']` is not updated, so if I run same script (which should change the `$_SESSION['checker']` variable), the while loop in the previously started script will still see the old `$_SESSION['checker']`. Why is it not updated?

Comment: `Hope its all make sense` I doubt that.

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify your question please?

Comment: I believe you should destroy that with the ajax part, not through PHP. Try .abort() on a current httprequest to stop it and start another.

Comment: Looking into websockets at the moment. Testing "websocketd" - looks like the way to go, easy to set up, works well with php, very light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP sessions do not support concurrent read/write operations by default. That is, when you update the $_SESSION array from one request, it does not propagate to an *already running* PHP request.

A solution is to create a file, and monitor the [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) (file modification time) of that file. Whenever we see that the file is updated, we know that another process [touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php)ed it.

Implementation example:

```
$filename = ".test_file";

// Update the file modification time to the current time
touch($filename);
$modificationTime = filemtime($filename);

while ($modificationTime === filemtime($filename) {
    // Do stuff, file modification time is not yet updated.
}

// The file modification time has been updated!
```

Note that you should test for the change frequently, depending on how quickly the first process should terminate, which means that the code inside the while loop should not take too long.

Comment: Isn't there a problem that the check for the filemtime of a file is to late, because then the other process is already running and also working it's magic, and possible interfering with one another?

Comment: Well, the process needs to be stopped as soon as another process has started. This script does that, but only every 'while'. If the process inside the while takes a couple of seconds, it will take a couple of seconds after the second ajax call starts before the first one will stop. This could mean that both calls run for a small amount of time before the first one is stopped. This could potentially be a problem depending of the wishes of the developer

Comment: How do we change the file then? There will be one operation already running (the one we want to stop). Kind of catch 22 :)

Comment: Just did a bit more testing - looks like PHP (or rather apache) queuing all the requests from the same client.

Comment: @user3195616 To modify the file, just make another request for the same resource. The new request will touch the file and thus update its modification time. The fact that Apache queues requests is a different and unrelated issue.

Comment: It will be tricky to get one to stop and the other to start running. The only way I can think of that is kind of doable is to have a timestamp written to a file (like the example), and a stopfile written as soon as the second scripts starts running, once the first run sees the stopfile, it stops and removes the stopfile. Meanwhile a sleep could check if the stopfile was removed and start the running again, so the second one will start after the first one actually stopped

Answer (score 1):

You might want to tackle this from the ajax side instead of the PHP side.
You can stop current http requests through abort, something like:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: "parameter=input&type=test",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: Does this actually kill the PHP process though?

Comment: good question, I don't think so *'One thing to note is that abort() will cancel the request from the browser's perspective, but if the request has already been successfully sent to the server, the server will still process everything. The browser simply will respond to any data/response sent back by the server.'*

Comment: It doesnt kill PHP process, php script still running on the server, its just browser stops listening